# Apply function to more than one column in R

Tags: r, loops

I read a few posts about it but still didn't get the answer. It is probably something simple that I'm missing. I have the function

```
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item1, mydata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95)
```

But I'd like to apply it automatically to other columns in my data frame instead of doing manually for every item

```
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item1, mydata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95)
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item2, mydata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95)
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item3, mydata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95)
```

Can someone help me how to create a loop? Is there another useful way of doing this?

Thanks!

*** SOLVED ***

I managed to use this code to find the solution

```
install.packages("magicfor") #Install Magicfor
library(magicfor) #Load Magicfor package
magic_for(print, silent = TRUE) #Load Magic for
for(coln in c(2:41)) {
  print(GoodmanKruskalGamma(newdata[,coln], newdata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95))
} #Perform loop
results <- magic_result_as_dataframe() #Storage results
results #Show results
```

*** ADDITIONAL QUESTION ***

How could I do a code to make the correlations between pairs of columns? For example, between an item and its restscore?

```
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item1, mydata$restscore1, conf.level=0.95)
GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata$item2, mydata$restscore2, conf.level=0.95)
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
for(coln in c(2:41)) {
    for(coln2 in c(48:87)) {
  print(GoodmanKruskalGamma(newdata[,coln], newdata[,coln2], conf.level=NA))}  
  } #Perform loop
```

EDIT : I found the second solution, for those interested

```
### Calculate Kruskal Gamma between Item and Restscore ###

results3 <- capture.output(
for(coln in c(2:41)) {
  for(restn in c(43:82)) {
  if(coln + 41 == restn){
  print(GoodmanKruskalGamma(newdata[,coln], newdata[,restn], conf.level=NA))
  }else{}
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you post reproducible data please?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(coln in c('item1', 'item2', 'item3')) {
   GoodmanKruskalGamma(mydata[,coln], mydata$totalscore, conf.level=0.95)
}
```

should do the trick